# find the derivative respect to $x$ and explain step by step?

Tags: calculus

Let $y = \sqrt{4-3x}$.

The problem is to find $\dfrac{d}{dx} \sqrt{4-3x}$, i.e. to find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

Let $u=4-3x$.   Then $y=\sqrt{u}$.

Then we have
$$
\frac{dy}{du} = ? or \frac{1}{2}(4-3x)^\frac{-1}{2},\qquad \text{and}\qquad \frac{du}{dx} = -3.
$$

Therefore
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx} =
$$

the right answer is  $\dfrac{-3}{2\sqrt{4-3x}}$

Can you please help me out? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct: if you put the pieces together, you get

$$\frac{dy}{du}=\frac12u^{-1/2}=\frac12(4-3x)^{-1/2}=\frac1{2\sqrt{4-3x}}\;,$$ and $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-3\;,$$ so by the chain rule $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=\left(\frac1{2\sqrt{4-3x}}\right)(-3)=\frac{-3}{2\sqrt{4-3x}}\;.$$ If some part of that is not clear, can you explain exactly where the difficulty is?

Comment: all clear thx! @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @SbSangpi: You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{g(x)}$ , then using chain rule we have :

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt {g(x)}} \cdot g'(x)$$

Comment: thx! can u plz solve the quation in that method? I would like to know the steps! :D